# how to secure our mongodb database ? Is it posible without change our pymongo 'MongoClient()'code?

Tags: python, mongodb, localhost, admin, database

hi I have a problem how can I solve it, problem is I have a python code which connect to mongodb database at my localhost like

```
    from pymongo import MongoClient
ip='localhost'
class Authentication():

    def __init__(self):
        try:
            client = MongoClient(host=host,port=port)
            db = client['Testdatabase']
            self.coll = db['testcollection']
            print 'database created successfully'
        except Exception('database not created') as e:
            print e
    def insert_data(self,data):
        if data:
            self.coll.save(data)

    def fetch_data(self):
        results = self.coll.find({})
        if results:
            for result in results:
                print result                           
    if __name__=='__main__':
        data = {'id':483,'name':'anil.c','age':32}
        auth = Authentication()
        auth.insert_data(data)                
        auth.fetch_data()
```

this is working good....
then i created a user on mongodb admin  with username & password and enbeld authrization,after that my database connection not wroking why?
I did'nt change my MongoClient as :

```
client = MongoClient('mongodb://username:password@127.0.0.1')
```

I need it like as:

```
client = MongoClient(host=host,port=port)
```

with authentication. 
If someone know about this pls give me suggestion.

Comment: if you have enabled authentication, system expects credentials to authenticate against. What are you expecting? Ignore security?

Comment: Thanks to comment , I have done it

Answer (score 1):

this is is very simple, crate user in your admin like this:

```
>use admin
>db.createUser({user: "Admin",pwd: "localhost",roles: [ { role: "root", db: "admin" } ] })
```

you will get user successfully added , after make modification in your code like:

```
from pymongo import MongoClient
class Authentication():
    def __init__(self):
       try:
          password = urllib.quote_plus(MONGO['password'])
          user = 'admin'
          client = MongoClient('mongodb://'+user+':'+password+'@'+MONGO['host'])
                    db = client['Testdatabase']
                    self.coll = db['testcollection']
                    print 'database created successfully'
                except Exception('database not created') as e:
                    print e
```

go to mongo config file  cd /etc/mongod.conf,edit it, if you are using version <2.6 make 'auth=true' or if mongo version >3.0 authrization: enabled
save it and restart your monogd server like:

```
$sudo service mongod start
```

it works fine with authentication